# Removed column and index keeps re-adding itself during migrations

Tags: entity-framework, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I've discovered a Foreign key column in a table that wasn't matched by an entry in the Models file for that entity.
First tried to remove it like this (because its not referenced in the code, as it isn't in the Models file)

```
        migrationBuilder.Sql("alter table mytable drop constraint if exists myfk");
        migrationBuilder.Sql("drop index if exists myindex");
        migrationBuilder.Sql("alter table mytable drop column if exists myunusedFKcolumn");
```

This removed it, but then the code began to error, as it seemed to need that relation in one specific place where that relation isn't relevant.

So I re-added it (along with FK relation and index), and in a next migration, tried to remove it cleanly, like this (thinking that doing it the EF way would be more clean than directly in the database):

```
        migrationBuilder.DropForeignKey(
            name: "myfk,
            schema: "myschema",
            table: "mytable");

        migrationBuilder.DropIndex(
            name: "myindex",
            schema: "myschema",
            table: "mytable");

        migrationBuilder.DropColumn(
            name: "myunusedFKcolumn",
            schema: "myschema",
            table: "mytable");
```

But whatever I do, the migrations continue to automatically add myfk and myindex back in the next migration.
How to get rid of this happening?

Comment: are these objects in the model (i.e. edmx file)?

Comment: They were about 5 months ago, but were removed by a colleague, because the relation  myfk respresented, was accomplished via another related entity instead,  There are no edmx file in the project, only the regular model files